# Where clause is ambiguous Codeigniter Models

Tags: codeigniter

I have code in models

```
function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    // Join  Table
    $this->db->join('test_1_category','test_1_category.category_id = test_1_product.category_id','RIGHT');                  

    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPwUm.png)

there a solution?

Comment: What exactly you want to produce the output ? Is it like parent child of categories ?

Comment: both table have same field name that is why you are getting that error. use alias to avoid that.

Comment: ya, categories in product

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are performing right join for test_1_product with test_1_category.But codtion for on is `test_1_category.category_id = test_1_product.category_id`. So it shows ambiguous error at fetching rows because The RIGHT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the right table (table2), with the matching rows in the left table (table1). The result is NULL in the left side when there is no match.so just try like this...

```
function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    // Join  Table
    $this->db->join('test_1_category','test_1_product.category_id = test_1_category.category_id','RIGHT');   //query was ambiguous here                

    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```